# How can I organize two lists? string

Tags: string

I have two long lists. One is names....John, Paul, Gorge, and Ringo etc x 50,000
each guy has a number. The numbers are after all the names in order. SO its like 45, 32, 22, 65. 32 is Pual. 45 is John etc. How can I format this so that each name goes with the number.

Thanks

string

Comment: You'll need to be more specific novak. You have two lists where? What programming language are you using? etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to split each string into an array; most languages have a split() function that splits a string on a given delimiter.

```
String[] nameArray = nameList.split(",");
String[] numberArray = numberList.split(",");
```

Now you have two arrays, where `numberArray[247]` contains the number that goes with the name in `nameArray[247]` (for example).

So you could, for example, loop through them:

```
for (int i=0; i<nameArray.length; i++) {
   println(nameArray[i] + " : " + numberArray[i];
}
```

It may be different depending on what language you're using, of course.  The above examples are java-ish; in ruby the equivalent could be something like

```
Hash[*nameArray.zip(numberArray).flatten].each {|key, value| puts "#{key} : #{value}" }
```

EDITED TO ADD:
Here's an example using a space delimiter, and doing it in Python (disclaimer: I don't know Python particularly):

```
names = "John Paul George Ringo"
numbers = "11 12 13 14"
nameArray = names.split(" ")
numberArray = numbers.split(" ")
for i in range(len(nameArray)):
    print nameArray[i] + ": " + numberArray[i]
```

Comment: Also my list looks like this John Paul Goorge Ringo Names Names Names 43 54 65 23 12 numbers numbers numbers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to turn it into a dictionary and you're starting with a python list (not a string used as a list):

```
base_list = ["John", "Paul", "Joe", 4, 5, 6]
names = []
numbers = []

for item in base_list:
    if isinstance(item, int): 
        # Checks if the item is an instance of int.
        # If it's a string, you can use the string's 'isdigit' function instead
        numbers.append(item)
    else: 
        names.append(item)

nameNumber = {}

for i in range(len(names)):
    # Iterate through a range of numbers from 0 to the size of names
    nameNumber[names[i]] = numbers[i]
```

This outputs `{'Paul': 5, 'John': 4, 'Joe': 6}`

If you just want to reorder your list so it goes name then number you can change the last few lines like so:

```
nameNumber = []

for i in range(len(names)):
    nameNumber.append(names[i])
    nameNumber.append(numbers[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data

```
name_list = ["John", "Paul", "Gorge", ...]
number_list = [45, 32, 22, ...]
```

try

```
zip(name_list, number_list)
```

which contains

```
("John", 45)
("Paul", 32)
("Gorge", 22)
...
```

:)